# Denominator for mean and standard deviation of salary: the number of people or the number in work?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

I am contacting recent graduates and trying to find out how much are they earning. However, there are unemployed graduates. So when I calculate the mean salary or standard deviation of our graduates, should I divide by number of graduates who responded and are employed or the total number of graduates?

Comment: Welcome to our site! I find this question quite unclear at the moment. What do you mean by "I am not working with a sample"? I think the real answer to this question turns on "find how much *they* are earning": does *they* refer only to those who are employed?

Comment: I am sorry, let me try again. I am contacting recent graduates and trying to find out how much are they earning. Now there are unemployed graduates. So, when i calcukate mean salary or standard deviation of our graduates,should i divide by number of graduates responded and employed or total number of graduates? I hope this is clear.

Comment: I think this is much clearer now. Thank you for your efforts! I have made some edits to the title, if you don't like them you can always replace them.

Comment: Perhaps you should first decide what information you want to communicate and then choose a set of statistics relevant to that information.  In particular, do you want to describe your employed graduates or all your graduates?  If it's the latter, would you actually find it meaningful to lump them all together into a group and report statistics for that group, or would it be more meaningful for your purposes to report on the employed and unemployed graduates separately? Only you can tell us which approach is relevant.

Comment: (For what its worth, in my experience most "average salary" calculations are shown *only for employed people*. But as your post illustrates, this is of only limited use if some people are not employed and we don't know how many.)

Answer (score 1):

Unemployed people are one reason that average salaries are usually denoted in literature by the median, not the mean. If you use the median as the average, it does not matter quite so much whether they are included or not.

As an aside, another reason is outliers on the other side: people making many, many more times than the average which can skew the mean badly. If you want to communicate what the average person is making, the one person making $100,000,000 a year is not really relevant.